# Airflow DAG Run failed and made other DAG Run to failed also

Tags: airflow

In airflow UI I run the same DAG twice, the two DAG Runs run in parallel for the same DAG, and each has a different parameter that I send, the first run is supposed to fail and the second one is supposed to run successfully - but I notice that the first run that failed made the other run to failed also.
there are no dependencies between the runs.
I use Airflow version 2.5.1 and Celery Executorin airflow configuration.

In this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EShoE.png), you can see that the first run failed in his first task, but if you look at the second run, you can see that his first task succeeded, but the tasks after it are in the status of "upstream-failed" even though nothing upstream was marked with failed - this indicates strongly that there is something connecting the two dag runs although there should be no connection between them.

Comment: Please post sample code to reproduce your issue. This may be related to, for example,  `depends_on_past` value.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Sharing the task logs would also be helpful

Answer (score 0):

you can delete the first dag file to validate that the second dag works independently,and check the result, hope can help u